# How to display .ico image file in IE

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, default.png, .ico

I have uploaded .ico file for favicon and its working fine as favicon in all browsers. But when i try to show this .ico file in HTML image tag in IE, it is not displayed correctly. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't serve favicons which doesn't have the `type="image/x-icon"` on it.

So for favicons for IE, you should use this:
`<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />`

For showing the icon as a `img` tag, the best solution I can think of is trying another format. If you are uploading the icons manually, then I would convert them with an image program.

If you a system which allows users to upload icons, then I would use the [GD](http://www.php.net/gd) or [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/imagick) library to convert those.

Comment: thanks for your quick ...
can you refer me some example of GB or ImageMagick library for converting .ico to .png as i searched and did nt find one.

Comment: can you refer me some example of GB or ImageMagick library for converting .ico to .png as i searched and did nt find one

Comment: Sorry for my misspelling, it is called GD. But here is a example of the usage of ImageMagick. `convert "favicon.ico" -thumbnail 16x16 -alpha on -background none -flatten "favicon.png"`.

Comment: Is this solved? Could you then mark this as the answer?